# Add Authentication to .Net Core 2.0 Angular Template

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to implement authentication with .Net core 2.0 angular template (in visual studio 2017). I have attempted with asp.net Identity trying to follow [this tutorial](https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login.)

I am getting stuck right away with adding the dbContext to startUp.cs.

**StartUp.cs:**

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddDbContext<EduSmartContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

I get this error In startup.cs when adding applicationDbContext:

> the type 'EduSmart.Data.ApplicationDbContext' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method
>   'EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext(IServiceCollection,
>   Action, ServiceLifetime, ServiceLifetime)'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'EduSmart.Data.ApplicationDbContext' to
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'. EduSmart
>   C:\src\EduSmart\Startup.cs 30 Active

**I am looking for one of these three options:**

1. Resolve the error above.
2. A link to a more clear step by
           step tutorial to implement authentication with asp.net Identity
3. Suggest a better way to authenticate Angular Asp.Net core app  with
   a linked resource

Comment: Why having two separate `DbContext`s ?

Comment: @KavehG because I had already had a Context that inherited from DbContext.

Comment: I'll be posting an answer and through some QA maybe we can reach a gool solution for you

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more code, I guess

> 1.Resolve the error above.

As it states your `ApplicationDbContext` is not derived from DbContext. And I think moving your `EduSmartContext` entities to the `ApplicationDbContext` will do the job for you.

```
public class EduSmartContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public EduSmartContext(DbContextOptions<EduSmartContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Poco1> Poco1s { get; set; }
        ...
        ...
```

> 2.A link to a more clear step by step tutorial to implement authentication with asp.net Identity

You are better off searching for token based authentication with Asp.net core webapi.
https://logcorner.com/token-based-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-core/

> 3.Suggest a better way to authenticate Angular Asp.Net core app with a linked resource

If you're willing to invest on this, I suggest that you use an Authentication Server also known as STS (security Token Server)
such as [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/) or [OpenIdDict](https://github.com/openiddict)
In case of IdentityServer this articles might be helpful:

https://damienbod.com/2016/10/01/identityserver4-webapi-and-angular2-in-a-single-asp-net-core-project/

Comment: Will check it out. Any thoughts/opinions on auth0?

Comment: @AmetureBoss Auth0 is a paid for service that implements specifications such as OpenID Connect 1.0 & OAuth 2.0. They own the code and typically host it on their infrastructure. User management is provided out of the box which in case of identityserver or OpenIdDict you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Open source authentication options for ASP.NET Core listed in the documentations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/community